# How to check permission on synonym in Microsoft SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, synonym

I want to update a table in databse B, from a trigger in database A. The trigger in database A is fired via different user accounts, which may or may not have permission on Database B. It works fine with the users which have permission on database B.

However, when trigger is fired under a user account, it throws exception because user does not have permission on the object referred by the Synonym. Is there a way to check permission on the object referred by Synonym so that I can avoid the exception when user does not have permission?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found it in documentation. Below query did the trick.

```
IF (SELECT HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME('ams.syn_bkgsvcattribute', 'OBJECT', 'INSERT'))>0
  print 'yes'
else
  print 'no'
```

Comment: Note that permissions on indirectly referenced objects (i.e. by the trigger) are not needed if the ownership chain is unbroken.  In the case of objects in different databases, the DB_CHAINING database option must be turned on and the databases must have the same owner (for dbo-owned objects).